# Where are vBulletin 5 URLs stored in database?

Tags: vbulletin

its been so long for me to find this... all in vain. Can you guys tell me where are the URLs stored in the database? which table? i want to modify the URLs manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've found it already.

URL's are stored in `urlident` column in `node` table.